# Are ES2015+ intrinsic objects equivalent to built-in objects in ES 5.1?

Tags: javascript

AFAICT ES2015 brings in new nomenclature "intrinsic objects".

Are ES2015+ intrinsic objects equivalent to built-in objects in ES 5.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly, they are a subset of them.

From the spec [§6.1.7.4 Well-Known Intrinsic Objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-well-known-intrinsic-objects) (emphasis mine):

> Well-known intrinsics **are built-in objects** that are explicitly
>   referenced by the algorithms of this specification and **which** usually
>   **have [Realm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-code-realms)
>   specific identities**. Unless otherwise specified each
>   intrinsic object actually corresponds to a set of similar objects, one
>   per [Realm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-code-realms).

The definition of built-in objects in [§4.3.9 built-in object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-built-in-object) still applies:

> object specified and supplied by an ECMAScript implementation

which is really everything not created by the user. See also [§17 ECMAScript Standard Built-in Objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-standard-built-in-objects).

So there are also many built-in objects that are not intrinsics (e.g. well-known symbols, global objects, methods of intrinsics, methods of other built-in objects).