# What is Realm and Why do we Need it(ecma262)?

Tags: javascript

What is Realm according to **ecma262** and why do we need it ?

All i found about the why question is.

> Before it is evaluated, all ECMAScript code must be associated with a realm

Well... it doesn't help much :(

Why all ECMAScript code must be associated with [realm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-code-realms) ?

I've seen that [Realm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-code-realms) has something weird called `[[Intrinsics]]` `[[TemplateMap]]` `[[HostDefined]]` and it has something more familiar `[[GlobalObject]]` and  `[[GlobalEnv]]`

I've also seen that every Execution Context has Realm.

so can anyone explain to me what is a Realm and why do we need it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to understand JS realms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49832187/1048572)?

Comment: i've been looking at that question. but still i don't really understand it

Comment: As for what intrinsics are, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38199520/1048572)

Comment: Hey @Bergi can you take a look at my latest question "How the evaluate operation works in ecmascript?" it's different than my older question about the evaluation operation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to understand JS realms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832187/how-to-understand-js-realms)